# Splash screen showing on shut down but not at boot

Tags: boot, grub2, nvidia, plymouth

I have a PC with an nvidia card and ubuntu 16.04. My splash screen only shows up when i shut down the computer, but not when I boot. I followed instructions to fix for nvidia cards and other fixes but only works for shut down splash screen. It is still a black screen instead of the splash screen with the logo and stuff whenever i turn on ubuntu. Any suggestions on this? thanks in advance!